# Adobe Acrobat Exhibit Label stamps with incrementing capital letter

Tags: javascript, increment, alphabetical

I routinely use numerically incrementing Adobe Acrobat Exhibit Label stamps and have long struggled to create JS or modify JS which will incrementally apply a capital letter when applying exhibit stamps on multiple documents.  I have created numerous Exhibit Label stamps in different configurations with numerical incrementing.

Extensive search for Adobe Acrobat JS code online with the most helpful code found in the StackOverflow question 125040442 ("What is a method that can be used to increment letters").  That said, I am still having issues implementing.

```
if(event.source.forReal && event.source.stampName == "#dFy_HzikDGIAs7PGXRwfvD")
{
if(typeof(app.media.nExhibit)== "undefined")
app.media.nExhibit = 1;
else
app.media.nExhibit++;
event.value = app.media.nExhibit;
}
```

To have JS embedded in the Adobe Acrobat Exhibit Label stamp in: Text Field Properties > Calculate tab > Custom calculation script.  Open a document, apply the stamp with the first letter, save and close the document, open the next document and apply the stamp with the next capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

So you want `event.value` to be a capital letter that keeps incrementing to the next letter? Right now, you're using a value of 1, then 2, then 3, etc. You need to use the character codes of the letters, increment that, and then convert back to a letter. You can get the character code of a letter using `chartCodeAt`, and convert a code back to a letter using `String.fromCharCode`. So:

```
if(event.source.forReal && event.source.stampName == "#dFy_HzikDGIAs7PGXRwfvD") {
    if(typeof(app.media.nExhibit)== "undefined")
        app.media.nExhibit = 'A'.charCodeAt(0);
    else
        app.media.nExhibit++;
    event.value = String.fromCharCode(app.media.nExhibit);
}
```

You may also want to make sure it can't pass Z; for that you can simply chance if it's greater than `'Z'.charCodeAt(0)` when you increment and set it back to A's character code. (You can also do it in one line with some modular arithmetic, if you like.)

Comment: Thank you . . . will try this

Comment: The first stamp placement resulted in a blank exhibit label. However, the next and successive placements did result in an incremented letter.  Many thanks.